# React component not replaced

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm new to React and redux. I'm having an issue when navigating through URLs. (Please look into below files). Index.js is my react file linked with html page with id 'index'. In Index.js file i'm rendering the Home.jsx file's 'Home' component. In Home.jsx file, I have added two Routes- List, AddForm, with paths shown there. Also there i have rendered a react component 'HomeNavBar'. AddForm.js and ListBox.jsx are react files with AddForm and List components respectively. HomeNavBar.jsx with HomeNavBar component has a Link 'add' as shown there. By default the List component is shown. When clicking the Link with 'add' i want to replace the List component with AddForm component which is rendered from AddForm.js. Now the problem is When i click the Link, the url in address bar is changing. but the component is not changing. Still the List component is shown. No errors in console. Some one please help me. (Seriously i want to do this with routers)

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store/store';
import Home from './Home.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
           <Home />
                </Provider>, document.getElementById('index'));
```

Home.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import List from './ListBox.jsx';
import AddForm from './AddForm.react.js'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomeNavBar from './HomeNavBar.jsx'

class Home extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
                -------blah blah----
                <div>Blah blah balh</div>
                <HomeNavBar />
                <div>
                <Router>
                <Switch>

                    <Route exact path="/" component={List} />
                    <Route path="/add" component={AddForm} />

                </Switch>
                </Router>
                </div>
                ------blah--blah--------
          )}}
export default Home
```

AddForm.js

```
also a react file with some html form contents
```

ListBox.jsx

```
also a react file with some html contents
```

HomeNavBar.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class HomeNavBar extends React.Component {

render() {
    return(
      <Router>
            <div>
                 <li><Link to={'/add'}>Add Movie</Link></li>
                 --------blah blah blah-------------------
            </div>
     </ Router>
    );
}
 }
export default HomeNavBar
```

web.config file is

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,

  entry: './assets/js/components/Index.react.js', // entry point of our app. assets/js/index.js should require other js modules and dependencies it needs

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
      filename: "[name].js",
  },

  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader', query:{ plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy'] }}, // to transform JSX into JS
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'class-to-classname', query:{ plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy'] }}, // to transform JSX into JS
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
}
```

Please kindly look the [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qmhbv4?embed=1&file=index.js)

In the demo you can see that, when i click the **Add movie** the url is changing but content is not. the content changes only on refresh.

Answer (score 2):

Move **HomeNavBar** inside *Router* tag in your **Home** component

```
class Home extends React.Component {
render(){
    return(
            <div>
            <Router>
             <div>
              <HomeNavBar />
               <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={List} />
                <Route path="/add" component={AddForm} />
               </Switch>
              </div>
             </Router>
            </div>
      )}}
```

and remove *Router* in **HomeNavBar** component

```
class HomeNavBar extends React.Component {
render() {
    return(
            <div>
                 <li><Link to={'/add'}>Add Movie</Link></li>
            </div>
    );
}
```

Here is the [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o6khfw)

Comment: Hey Igor, thanks for helping, but my issue is not solved. i have updated my question with a demo. Please kindly look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste the following- 
in **Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import HomeNavBar from './HomeNavBar.js'
import List from './ListBox.js';
import AddForm from './AddForm.js'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Home extends React.Component {
   render(){
     return(<Router>
               <div>
               <HomeNavBar/>
               <div>
                <Route exact path="/" component={List} />
                <Route path="/add" component={AddForm} />
               </div>
               </div>
          </Router>);
    }
}

export default Home
```

in **homeNavBar.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class HomeNavBar extends React.Component {
      render() {
         return(
              <div>
                   <Link to='/add'>Add Movie</Link>
              </div>
               );
    }
}

export default HomeNavBar
```

**The Problem was caused by:** 
Wrapping your `<Link />` inside a `<Router />` AND not enclosing your entire rendered components inside `<Router />`. Someone else can probably explain the cause better.

Comment: Hey MinorityDev, thanks for Helping, but my issue is not solved. i have updated my question with a demo. Please kindly look into it.

Comment: @PiyalGeorge there you go :) changed answer, confirmed working on the demo you provided

Comment: Oh shit Thanks, Thanks, Thanks, Thanks, Thanks, Thanks... infinite Thanks. You Great has finally found it. I have been sitting on this issue for days. Thanks So much man. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have messed up your routes. Please find below few suggestions:

- You can wrap your routes in some component which will render the routes and can also have nav links. In your case if you use `HomeNavBar`, it will be something like this,

  ```
   <Router>
     <HomeNavBar>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={List} />
        <Route path="/add" component={AddForm} />
      </Switch>
     </HomeNavBar>
   </Router>
  ```
- You have defined routes again in your `HomeNavBar`. I think those are
  not needed. It can be plain and simple. You can use `NavLink` instead on `Link` here,

  ```
  ...
  <div>
    <NavLink to="/add">Add Movie</NavLink>
    ...
  </div>
  <div>
    {this.props.children}
  <div>
  ...
  ```

Hope this helps.

**Update :** [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-98zzzt?file=HomeNavBar.js) based on above suggestions

Comment: Hey Dev, thanks for Helping, but my issue is not solved. i have updated my question with a demo. Please kindly look into it.

Comment: Thanks man, but still didn't work, if you could edit my own demo, how could i do that.